# Android Ouku tablet device drivers

Tags: android, drivers

I am developing (not end user), on Eclipse and I want to connect to Ouku tablet. I cannot find the drviers for this that work. Anyone know how to get Ouku tablet connected via USB.  I cannot even see the device

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the android update adb command, or manually putting the VID into your adb_usb.ini file (even though it telss you not to)?

```
more ~/.android/adb_usb.ini 
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
```

You may need to use dmesg or lsusb or look in device manager to figure out the VID; also on linux you may need to put it in your udev rule.

Finally, do your know for a fact that this device has an adbd listening on USB?  First make sure you have enabled USB debugging in settings. If you can get a shell open from a terminal program or connectbot on the device, you might want to try

```
getprop | grep adb
```

and

```
ps | grep adbd
```

Comment: I'm on samsung tablet as well as Ouku.  How woudld I view dmesg or lsusb?  How would I get to such a prompt? Thanks

Comment: Open a terminal on your linux development machine, or boot off of a linux livecd and do so if you don't run it ordinarily.

Comment: Well I am running on Eclipse on Windows PC.  And connecting to various Android Devices.  How could I view smesg or lsub etc?

Comment: You could do what I suggested in my previous comment, and boot off of a live linux cd so that you can run linux for a few minutes, where dmesg and lsusb are available by default.  There are ways to accomplish similar things on windows, but they may take longer to track down.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could also help, came accross this [driver link](http://www.geeksphone.com/downloads/drivers_qcom_7x27_BLINK.zip)
On this [page](http://forum.geeksphone.com/index.php?topic=1826.30)

I had a P801W with VID: 0x05C6

After installing the driver package and updating the devices:

1. Update Driver
2. Select option: "Browse My Computer for Driver Software"
3. Select option: "Lett me pick from the list"
4. Select Mobile -> Google Inc -> ADB Interface

I had to to this for 4 new devices in my list, but after these steps $adb shell worked on me

Based on what I have learned today, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266393/eclipse-does-not-recognize-my-android-tablet/7267512#7267512) could also provide good information in resolving this with the standard USB ADB Drivers from Google, by simply modifying the driver .inf description file.