# Eclipse does not recognize my Android tablet

Tags: android

I'd like to start by saying that I've been using Eclipse with an Android (v2.2) **phone** with no problems.

Today I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1) but Eclipse does not recognize it. Windows is aware of the device but Eclipse is not. I have installed the latest USB drivers, I can access the tablet as a storage device, the tablet is set to USB debugging mode and the tablet shows a "USB Debugging" notification when I plug it in. However it never shows up in the DDMS view in Eclipse and I cannot install or debug apps on it from Eclipse.

Any help is much appreciated.

Barry

Comment: update your google usb driver package with latest version. goto sdk manager and click available package

Comment: With Samsung's android stuff you usually get the correct drivers if you install/update Kies.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers but I tried everything you said and it still didn't recognize the tablet. Finally I just reinstalled the drivers and Kies and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way I solved this problem.

1. Connect your tablet to PC
2. PC will show Popup for new Hardware device found. On tab click on USB symbol (visible near time field.
3. On click on this USB symbol it will show "Connected as Media device". Change that setting to "Camera"
4. Now run adb devices command in command prompt, it will show tab there

Answer (score 6):

1. Download device driver.
2. Make sure that you make it a developer device by checking the box in:

> Settings --> Applications --> Development --> "USB Debugging"

=====
UPDATED ANSWER:

For newer devices (4.0+), you will have to do it in two steps:

1. `Settings --> About --> Software Information --> Build number` (you might have to click 'more' in menu option... somehow each to "Build number".)
   Tap 7 times the row, and it will change device into 'developer mode'.
2. Once you done that, go back and check the box in `Settings --> Developer Options --> USB debugging`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, its not eclipse who is not recognizing your device. Its [ADB - android debug bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html). Usually you can check whether device is visible to ADB via console/terminal using `adb devices` (`adb` is an executable located at `$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools`).

Also, even if Windows sees your device as USB device, it doesn't mean it sees it as ADB compatible device. These are usually two different drivers. Make sure you've installed correct ADB drivers for your device.

Comment: I already had the ADB drivers installed for my phone. But just to be safe I upgraded to the latest drivers from Samsung. When I plugged in the tablet for the first time with USB debugging enabled the Windows notification said (among other things) "ADB Compatible Device Detected" and the drivers installed successfully. But it still does not appear in adb or Eclipse. :(

Comment: Make sure you've enabled USB debugging in tablet in "Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging".

Answer (score 2):

**Install [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL)** that will be enough to recognize your Android Tablet,
it contains the necessary drivers to work with your Android Sambung tablet

Answer (score 2):

Download Samsung Kies 2.0, it will install the drivers you need.

http://www.samsungapps.com/about/onPc.as

After the necessary restart my tablet installed the rest automatically (Win7) and the device is visible in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (android 3.0). Windows 7 did recognize it as a generic storage device, but not as the Galaxy Tab. 
If I remember correctly, there was an unknown device in the Windows Device Manager and pointing Windows to the
`android_winusb.inf` to install a driver for it didn't work.

I solved the problem by editing the file `<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf` according to a post I found somewhere on the Internet.
The file should contain the following:

```
;Galaxy Tab 10.1v
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&REV_9999&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6601
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7000
```

This should appear two times in the file; once under `[Google.NTx86]` (for 32-bit) and once under `[Google.NTamd64]` (for 64-bit).
Then reinstall the driver by pointing Windows to the edited .inf file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install Android 3.1 SDK and install the eclipse classic plugins as well.
I have been using Samsung Galaxy with eclipse from quite some time now.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help. :(

Comment: Are you able to fix your problem?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. Please see my comment in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think u doesnot have android sdk 3.1 installed in your eclipse.

Goto Eclipse Window menu -> Android SDK and AVD Manager

Now goto Available Packages from where you can Download and install Android sdk platform for 3.1

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

1- Install the correct device driver from [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP?) onto your workstation.

2- Pick the correct API level for your project, i.e. 3.1

3- Turn on "USB debugging" on your mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, with my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos.
It was perfectly working fine.. we could debug.

Stopped working/ not recognizable, after reinstalling the OS, Eclipse etc.

Here's a FIX that might work:

1. Go to Android SDK Manager.
2. Delete /Uninstall the USB drivers.
3. Reconnect your mobile /tablet.
4. The appropriate drivers will be installed automatically.
5. Your Eclipse could identify your device... Your device is ready for debug.

SSS Solutions
www.s3s.co.in

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for a Galaxy Note 10.1:

- Install the Kies driver set available from Samsung as described
  above.
- to Set the Galaxy Note's USB Debugging on.
- Set the Galaxy Note to Camera Mode in the USB menu after plugging in
  the USB cable to PC.
- Run CMD window and manually run "adb usb" from the android-v4 directory
- CMD run "adb devices" and the Note showed up as:

"**List of devices attached**

**4107001b9836affb        device**"

Now when I hit "run" in eclipse, I see "samsung-gt_n8013-4107001..." as a target device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Enable USB debugging on your device.

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

> Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number 7 times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.